# Can I add Build Steps for ARM templates in VS2017

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Does anyone know if its possible to add a build step in VS2017 which would run the deploy PS script?
Essentially, I'm thinking of saving time by validating the ARM templates in the build step, using the $validateonly switch which is available on the ps1. however I can't see the option to add a build step to an ARM template project. Is the type of project the issue here?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295454/solution-wide-pre-build-event

Comment: It won't actually save time unless your builds consistently have errors. In the end, you'll be validating twice. Once on build, once on deploy. The only way it would save time is if your builds error out more often than they succeed. (Having said that, I'm interested if there's a way to do it too, as I think semantically it makes sense having the template verified during build rather than deployment)